# Enabling ADFS Extranet Smart Lockout

Tags: office365, adfs, windows-server

I am trying to enable this ADFS feature but it appears the cmdlet required "Update-AdfsArtifactDatabasePermission" as per the Microsoft guide https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/operations/configure-ad-fs-extranet-smart-lockout-protection are missing with both Server 2016 and 2019.

The cmdlet is not available in the ADFS module, has anybody found a solution to this?

I come across the below GitHub post about these missing cmdlets / parameters but the issue has not been resolved.

https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/windows-powershell-docs/issues/1571

Interested as there appears to be many posts on the internet sugesting people have been able to configure this feature.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

•   This command may fail due to lack of sufficient permissions on the SQL Server instance and the database that is used for storing the ADFS configuration data or if using the Windows Internal Database, please check whether ‘System’ and ‘Trusted Installer’ permissions are set on the directory where the WID is hosted along with the ADFS Service Principal administrator and local administrator permissions.

•   Ensure while executing this command, the credentials that you are passing in the ‘$cred’ variable are having SQL database administrator permissions as well as ADFS administrator permissions too with ‘Enable delegation for service authentication’ permission assigned. Incase, if the required ADFS artifacts table in the database is still not created or updated, please execute the below script on the SQL database server: -

```
‘ # when prompted with “Are you sure you want to perform this action?”, enter Y.

 [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess=$true,ConfirmImpact = 'High')]
 Param()

 $fileLocation = 
 "$env:windir\ADFS\Microsoft.IdentityServer.Servicehost.exe.config"

 if (-not [System.IO.File]::Exists($fileLocation))
 {
  write-error "Unable to open ADFS configuration file."
   return
  }

  $doc = new-object Xml
  $doc.Load($fileLocation)
  $connString = 
  $doc.configuration.'microsoft.identityServer.service'.policystore.
  connectionString
  $connString = $connString -replace "Initial Catalog=AdfsConfigurationV[0-9]*", 
  "Initial Catalog=AdfsArtifactStore"

  if ($PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess($connString, "Executing SQL command 
   sp_addrolemember 'db_owner', 'db_genevaservice' "))
  {
  $cli = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
  $cli.ConnectionString = $connString
  $cli.Open()
  try
  {
  $cmd = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
  $cmd.CommandText = "sp_addrolemember 'db_owner', 'db_genevaservice'"
  $cmd.Connection = $cli
  $rowsAffected = $cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
  if ( -1 -eq $rowsAffected )
  {
  write-host "Success"
   }
  }
  finally
  {
   $cli.CLose()
   }
  } ‘
```

Or execute the below command in SQL by connecting to the ADFS SQL database.

```
 ‘ ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON SCHEMA::[ArtifactStore] TO [db_genevaservice] ‘
```

•   Also, please check whether the ADFS server on which you are executing this command is patched fully with all necessary updates or not. Restart the server after appropriate rights and permissions are set and then try again.

Please refer the below links for more information: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/operations/configure-ad-fs-extranet-smart-lockout-protection

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/identity/extranet-smart-lockout-feature

Comment: Hi, the problem is i cannot get as far even running this, the cmdlet is not present and yes the boxes are running the latest windows updates.

Comment: I would suggest you check the event viewer for any system state events for this condition and also, try restarting the server after updating is complete on it.

Comment: @KartikBhiwapurkar-MT The cmdlet `Update-AdfsArtifactDatabasePermission` does not exist in any PowerShell module available on a Windows 2019 server with ADFS installed. I'm hitting the same issue, searching for a solution.

Comment: @LarrySilverman, Try executing the below command on your domain joined ADFS server with the domain administrator account privileges on powershell post which you should be able to execute the command: - Set-AdfsProperties -EnableExtranetLockout $true -ExtranetLockoutThreshold 15 -ExtranetObservationWindow (new-timespan -Minutes 30) -ExtranetLockoutRequirePDC $false

Comment: Thanks @KartikBhiwapurkar-MT  I ultimately did find the `Set-AdfsProperties` command and solved my problem. Should have looped back around to update.

Comment: Great to know that your issue has been resolved. Cheers. Do upvote or accept the answer if found useful. Thank you.